# ultrawingrid: How can I change the idiom of filter operator description in the columns?

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I use Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v9.2, see the next image

[ultrawingrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXHzP.png)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Resources Customizer:

```
With Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.Resources.Customizer
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_Contains", "Contiene")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_DoesNotContain", "No contiene")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_DoesNotEndWith", "No termina con")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_DoesNotMatch", "No coincide con")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_DoesNotStartWith", "No comienza con")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_EndsWith", "Termina con")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_Equals", "=")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_GreaterThan", ">")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_GreaterThanOrEqualTo", ">=")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_LessThan", "<")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_LessThanOrEqualTo", "<=")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_Like", "Como")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_Match", "Coincida")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_NotEquals", "No igual a")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_NotLike", "No como")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDown_Operator_StartsWith", "Comienza con")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownAllItem", "(Todos)")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownBlanksItem", "(En Blanco)")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownCustomItem", "(Personalizado)")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownEquals", "Igual a")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownErrorsItem", "Erroneos")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownGreaterThan", "Mayor que")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownGreaterThanOrEqualTo", "Mayor o igual que")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownLessThan", "Menor que")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownLessThanOrEqualTo", "Menor o igual a que")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownLike", "Como")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownMatch", "Coincide expresión regular")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownNonBlanksItem", "(No En Blanco)")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownNonErrorsItem", "(No Erroneos")
    .SetCustomizedString("RowFilterDropDownNotEquals", "No es igual que")
End With
```

More strings at: http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/HTML/WinGrid_Resource_Strings.html

Saludos! :)